# Are WP 8 apps backwards compatible on WP 10?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, compatibility

We're about to develop an app for `WP 8` and the customer is asking for a `WP 10` app as well. I know `WP 8.1` can run the `WP 8` app just fine, but what about `WP 10`?

And if `WP 10` cán run the app; are there any downsides compared to building one for `WP 10` from scratch?